# Should Christians (Protestants) play God of War?

Tags: protestantism, morality, entertainment

I was going to play through the God of War series, and as a Christian, violence and even gore doesn't really bother me, nor does magic stuff as long as it doesn't resemble anything real, like from the occult, but the one thing that does bug me about ***God of War*** (aside from the nudity) is the **human sacrifice** needed to progress in the first game!

I'm very bugged about this. I really want to play the whole series, but as a Christian, the whole idea of sacrificing something, especially a person, even if it's just a game, doesn't sit well with me at all. I need fellow non-denominational Protestants to help me with this.

Does the Bible say such a thing would be an abomination even in fiction, even if you would never, ever even consider actually doing such a thing? I understand that if such a thing, even if it weren't a human sacrifice if attempted, would be beyond vile and repugnant before God and I would never do such a thing. Does He see it being done in the game the same way, according to Scripture?

Answer (score 0):

Glad you are stopping to consider the significance of the form of entertainment you engage in, this intentionality is a step in the right direction. Ultimately there are some unavoidably subjective issues at play here - you note that violence and gore doesn't 'bother you' although they may bother others. Nevertheless there are some basic considerations to every choice we make:

1. **Does playing this game glorify God?**
   1 Corinthians 10:31 follows a long discussion of whether it is okay for Christians to eat or drink this or that food. Paul concludes that in Christ, we are no longer under the law which makes us 'free' to eat or drink (or entertain ourselves) however we want, with the prerequisite that our freedom is always used to glorify God. Does playing this game utilize your freedom in Christ in a way that would make God pleased? If your conscience is telling you no, then at least for now, you should not play God of war. What about this game motivates you to play it?
2. **Does playing this game impact those around me negatively?**
   You say that violence doesn't bother you, but does it glorify violence, devalue life that God has made sacred, or bother those around you? Does the nudity in this game tempt you to sin or make the struggle of those around you more difficult? Does the human sacrifice included in it glorify Satanic practices, or even create a dangerous curiosity in you or those around you? If so, you should not play God of war. If they honestly don't bother you or those around you, I have to question
3. **Does playing this game contribute positively to the world?**
   I think this one is tricky because every choice we make can impact the world negatively without our direct involvement, but what do you know of the company that makes the game? Will your choice to purchase and play the game contribute to their profit margins such that the elements that drew you to the game (see point 1) are included in future games? How does playing this game and making in-game decisions, impact your view of the real world?

Comment: thank you. i won't show the game to anyone other than my mother, who is very wary of such things, and while i have intrusive thoughts about doing satanic rituals, witchcraft, or idol worship, i feel that this game, much like Asura's Wrath, will help expose the evil of idols and false gods, and show why only Yahweh is worthy. thank you.